# Maven issue after changing device

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, apache-poi

Trying to get back to the old project after changing the laptop and the poi.xml page keeps saying a problem occurred while I open the page. Doesn't allow me to run any thing at all in the project. Working on eclipse.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'scratchit'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6
```

Comment: _"poi.xml page"_ - you mean the `pom.xml` tab, right? _"after changing the laptop"_ - Did you use a fresh workspace on the new laptop in which you imported your projects (copying the workspace will not work in case paths have changed or when using a different Eclipse version)? Is your Eclipse up to date (please add the version to your question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use the latest version - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/dependency-info.html#apache-maven